# Is it possible to share a deamon between multiple app on iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

We developing a SDK communicating with a bluetooth device. We would like to share that SDK among multiple apps, is it possible to do that on iOS ?

I know that it is not possible with iOS 6.x and below but what about iOS 7.0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS apps are sandboxed, so it is not possible to implement something that shares a resource like that between the apps. The only way you could technically pass data between apps would be using custom URL schemes, but this requires bringing the app into the foreground.

For example, if you wanted an app to pass data to a second app, but wanted the first app to continue executing, you would use a custom URL scheme ("app2://somethinghere") that would invoke the second app while passing some parameter, then it would return to the first app by using another custom URL scheme ("app1://"). But this would be very jarring to the user, and would be very limited in what it could accomplish. Plus this still wouldn't allow the sharing of an active communication channel with a bluetooth device.

My suggestion, if you expect to have different apps running that all want to communicate with the device, is to be sure that your SDK properly closes the connection to the device upon backgrounding so that the next app can properly connect, since I assume there might be issues with the second one if the first one still has a connection.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have a daemon that is shared amongst multiple apps.